# Page formatting messing up on different resolutions and footer not working in general

Tags: html, css, footer, resolution

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I don't know any other web languages. 2 Questions:

1. When my website (zarwanhashem.com) is accessed using a different resolution than the one it was made on the header area at the top isn't filling up the page and the text is going beyond it as well. I didn't have this issue at first. Why is it messing up? Also, I'm not sure if you can see my CSS from inspect element.
2. The footer I created isn't showing up. It was working fine last night and I honestly have no clue what changed that made it stop working now. It isn't showing up.

Let me know if you need any other details. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Post the code in [JSFiddle](http://JSFiddle.net) and I'll help.

Comment: There could be a bunch of issues, it could be that your site is tailored to be at a specific setting (i.e. you are using a specific width and not accounting for any responsiveness), your other issue could be more of a browser specific issue, which, unfortunately happens all of the time. I would say post your code and link it to a JSFiddle -> www.jsfiddle.net -> and then link it to your question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32Fpt/ I only added the index page, but the CSS is there.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf I forgot to tag you

Comment: @BuddhistBeast can only tag one person per commment

Comment: Um, I am unable to fix this. Maybe recode it?

Comment: I am afraid of this position: absolute;

Comment: @Hassan "Recode it" isn't very helpful. @__@ And you'll have to be more specific about the absolute thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your footer is inside a misclosed comment `<!--footer->` instead of `<!--footer-->`